# Android App Development: Account Credentials and Database Backup

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to Android app development and have a few questions.

1. Suppose I want to create an app that has user login. I want to authenticate the users over the internet. Where should I collect and store all the user accounts and their credential information? Will this storage be free or paid?
2. Can I integrate Google Sign-in in my app for free? Where should I store the google sign-in account information of all the users?
3. Is it possible to integrate Google sign-in and backup the app database (.db files etc.) and other user settings to the user's Google Drive (for later recovery when app is reinstalled)? Is this free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

Answering Questions 1 and 2:

There are a few options:

1) **Firebase**:

If you only want to work on the mobile app, not on the backend software, the easiest way is Firebase.

Firebase has built-in support for Google authentication and you can follow the tutorials provided by Google [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), and the samples [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/a0e8c27bb60f82ac3dcae6ff1e3926d3b0ea4a69/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L73-L77). (I`m using the link because the code is too big to paste here on the answer.)   The authentication service is free.

2) **Self implementation**:
      You can use Google sign in API [on this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) and implement the server side if you have a backend team or want to do it yourself.

About Question 3 (Google drive), users can use their own Google account to store applications backups, and you can select what application files will be stored. In this case, they will consume their free Google Drive quota, and thus the service will be Free.
Google provides an API for that, and you can have have a look on [this example here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation). (Notice that Google had deprecated Google Drive Android API on December/2018. But the example on the link shows what you have to do on the newer way, using Drive REST API).

There are other approaches and solutions but I tried to give you the simplest and cheapest ones.

Comment: This helped. Thank you!